# Get "Default" Properties for Element in Website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a very basic website, and am currently working user creation. The user fills out a form, which then has the inputs validated and written to a MYSQL DB if valid.

I'd like to add some basic error checking while the user is inputting data - for example:

1. Validate the username the user is attempting to select against the Users table in the database.
2. Validate that the FirstName/LastName/Email fields contain values.
3. Validate that the password fields match.

You get the idea...if any of the above conditions fails, I'd like the label for the textbox to turn red, bold, and a slightly different size than the form otherwise, as well as provide a simple error message for the user somewhere on the page.

I've written a simple javascript function that can perform #2 and #3 above, and change the appropriate text to the "error" style.

My questions are:

1. How do I query the MYSQL db when the cursor exits the username field (to check if the username is still available)? I can easily do this when the user actually submits the form, but I'd like to query once it appears that the user is done typing, i.e. when the cursor leaves the textbox.
2. How do I display the simple error message on the page (and control what it says)?
3. How do I get the "default" or "standard" font size/weight/color values from the css stylesheet that controls the webpage's layout, so that I can then change the element back once the user corrects the error condition?
4. Is javascript even the right way to do this? I'm not incredibly familiar with it, but it seems similar enough to other languages I've worked with that I can kind of muddle through it.

Thank you in advance - if for some reason you think this question has been previously asked/answered, please provide a link for my benefit, as I was unable to find any questions directly on point.

Comment: Each of these should be a separate question. And you should try to solve them yourself, rather than asking broad open questions. If you have specific questions, that would be more appropriate.

Comment: Nobody's gonna answer this question, because this site isn't about theory or best practices, but code issues. Instead you should ask this question on Progammers.StackExchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost you need to understand that pure javascript in client side only. Something that the client could even turn off if the so desired.

Javascript is for display (like having fancy input validation or anything that could change the DOM after the page is loaded).

Server side languages like PHP is the only way you could talk to a MYSQL database. (Not saying that php is the only one-- others might include Ruby/Python/Node.js)

But everything you laid out here is a question/project itself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It sounds like javascript is what I need for most of my questions...I was hoping there would be some option like document.getElementById("stylesheet.css").("#labelName").("propertyname") as far as getting the CSS styles - sounds like that's not the case.

Comment: If you like the post please click the check mark below the updown arrow on the left.

Also you should check out jQuery for most of your need. Its a library that simplifies alot of javascript for you

Comment: The jQuery suggestion was definitely what I needed - looks like it answers 1, 2, and 4 for me. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to check some information without refreshing the page, you'll need to look into AJAX.
2. The most basic message would be something like `alert('That name is taken!')`.
3. You could add a new class to the form element with the error, so that it gets some additional CSS properties. Then once the user corrects the error, remove that class from the element and the browser will redraw the element with the original properties.
4. JavaScript will handle the AJAX request part and the changing styles part. Obviously the actual database querying will happen through your server-side language of choice. But it sounds like you're okay with that side.